# Installing pyspider - "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, linux, pip, debian, chromebook

I'm trying to install pyspider on Debian GNU/Linux 9. Tried installing with pip and pip3, checked libevent-dev, libpython-dev, python-dev, distribute, ez_setup, and I still get the following message from pip/pip3 install pyspider:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in tmp/pip-build-<randomcharacters>/pycurl/
```

Right above that error message, it says this:

```
__main__.ConfigurationError: Could not run curl-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'curl-config'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`pyspider` [requires `pycurl`](https://github.com/binux/pyspider/blob/3fccfabe2b057b7a56d4a4c79dc0dd6cd2239fe9/setup.py#L26) which in turn [requires `libcurl`](https://pypi.org/project/pycurl/). So install  [`libcurl`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/) first:

```
apt install libcurl4 libcurl4-openssl-dev
```